# backup Each Trigger in Seperate File in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I need to take backup of Each Trigger exist in system, but it should not include Table, only Triggers of every table. I want each Trigger to be created in a separate File and need to save it to a specific location?

i am not able to find anything related to how to save each trigger seperately? can anyone identify me what can be done in such scenario?

Comment: Although it shouldn't make a difference here, any reason why you've tagged 3 different versions of SQl Server? When you say "in system" do you mean in every database on the server?

Comment: SQL Server cannot produce or save files on its own (well, it *can*, but only through use of extended procedures -- I don't recommend it). Getting the definitions of triggers can be done through SMO, or through a piece of T-SQL (`SELECT m.[definition] FROM sys.triggers tr JOIN sys.tables t ON tr.[parent_id] = t.[object_id] JOIN sys.sql_modules m ON m.[object_id] = tr.[object_id]`). Separating out the definitions in files would require a bit of client code. You could also use Management Studio's "Generate Scripts" task and post-process the result of that, but that's more complicated.

Comment: This seems like the sort of thing that should be found in your *source control system*. You do source control your database schemas, don't you?

Answer (score 3):

Right click on your database in SQL Server Management Studio, select Start PowerShell and run following:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd 'SELECT name, OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) def FROM sys.triggers'
  | % { $_.def | out-file "E:\Temp\$($_.name).sql" }
```

Files will be generated in `E:\Temp`, named same as trigger name, with sql extension.